# VBA application-defined error when assigning new value in array

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write a function that takes in a variant array (2-dimensions), then goes through it and changes all dates to longs.

```
Private Function mlDateHelper(a As Variant)
    Dim i, j As Integer
    For i = 1 To UBound(a.value, 1)
        For j = 1 To UBound(a.value, 2)
            If IsDate(a(i, j)) Then
                a(i, j) = CLng(a(i, j)) 'This line errors out
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    mlDateHelper = a
End Function
```

Basically, I'm just iterating through the array on both dimensions, and whenever there's a date I'm trying to reset that date to a long.

When I'm debugging it, I can tell that it correctly computes `CLng(a(i, j))`, but then it crashes when it's trying to assign that value to a(i, j).

It's giving me an "application-defined or object-defined error". Thoughts? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Did you try adding a break point and seeing if the value you're trying to convert to a long is convertible to a long? Can you verify the program is executing up to that point?

Comment: is `a` the array that is being passed?

Comment: It is. I've added a breakpoint on that line and I can tell that `CLng(a(i, j))` is converted into a long. The error is on assigning it.

Comment: what is a? in Ubound you write a.value

Comment: `a` is of type Variant-- but it will always be a range passed in from excel. I had to use `a.Value` in UBound because UBound doesn't seem to work properly on a Variant.

Comment: You can check that `a` is an array before you use `UBound` to be sure. Example: `If IsArray(a) Then`

Comment: when I call your function like this (in immediate) `? mlDateHelper(selection)(1,1)` it results with what I expect.... no changes made to your function.

Comment: If you don't get an error on `UBound(a.value, 2)` then **a** is probably still a **Range** and so you need to say `a(i, j).Value = CLng(a(i, j))`. It depends whether you pass a Range to the function or assign the range to a variant first.

Comment: @Alec How do you call your function?

Answer (score 1):

If a is always a range, you should probably take advantage of that fact:

```
Private Function mlDateHelper(a As Range)
Dim c As Cell
For each c in a.Cells
    c.Value = CLng(c.Value)
Next
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I used MS-Access 2007 VBA to test this by removing the .value from the UBound statements as it would not compile in Access. I hope this works for you as it does for me (I had no problem with the assignment passing an array defined as Dim arr(1 To 5, 1 To 7) to the following function:

```
Private Function mlDateHelper(a As Variant)
    Dim i, j As Integer
    For i = 1 To UBound(a, 1)
        For j = 1 To UBound(a, 2)
            If IsDate(a(i, j)) Then
                a(i, j) = CLng(a(i, j)) 'This line errors out
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    mlDateHelper = a
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to whoever was looking into my question.

I actually discovered that I don't need this function because I can simply use the `a.Value2` property for the Variant, which does not attempt to convert dates into dates.

According to documentation I found: "*The only difference between this property and the Value property is that the Value2 property doesn’t use the Currency and Date data types. You can return values formatted with these data types as floating-point numbers by using the Double data type.*"

Thanks for helping though!